# Returning barcode result to text field in another activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, barcode-scanner

I have code working for a barcode scanner, but was wondering how could I return the result into a text field in a previous activity?

Answer (score 1):

If I get what your are asking, you have a class (maybe an activity?) that implements a barcode scanner and want to put what you get in a textview.

If the barcode scanner it's just a class, you can just return it. If it is an activity, you can call your barcode scanner activity with

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, YourBarcodeClass.class);
startActivityForResult(i, BarcodeCode);
```

With this the activity that calls the Barcode Scanner is able to catch a result when the acticity ends with

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    String code = data.getStringExtra("CustomKeyName");
}
```

In your barcode Scanner activity you have to attach the result to obtain in in onActivityResult when your activity ends, with something like

```
private void ReturntoActivity(){
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra("CustomKeyName", StringToReturn);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
    finish();
}
```

Hope I got what you needed and this helps